# Another way to solve the Dining Philosopher (need a point in the right direction)

Tags: java, multithreading, dining-philosopher

for a programming assignment I have been asked to implement a solution to the Dining Philosopher problem. I must do so in two ways:

1. Use the wait() and notifyAll() mechanism
2. Using an existing concurrent data structure provided in the Java API

I have already complete the first implementation. Which concurrent data structure is my professor talking about for step two? I don't remember her mentioning anything. I don't need any source code, just a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) Javadoc page to get some ideas.  These are not the only concurrent data structures (some of the java.util data structures also have built-in concurrency support) but this is a good starting point.

`Collections.synchronizedList` is not what I would call "an existing concurrent data structure" -- it is a wrapper for data structures that do not support concurrency.

Comment: Yes, the `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap` interface has several interesting methods in it that would allow you to implement a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps she meant wrapping Java collections in synchronized wrappers, e.g. using `Collections.synchronizedList()`, or the always synchronized data structures in `java.util.concurrent`, e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a data structure... but in the neighborhood of what you might need http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html?

Comment: If you're heading that direction, then java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock has some interesting methods. tryLock() in particular looks appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concurrent library in the Java API.

It has some collections

Look at the java.util.concurrent package

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html